# Using jQuery to slide one div open and one closed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to slide one div closed, and another open at the same time using a button. here is my div code:

```
<div class='toggle_parent'>
    <div class='toggleHolder'>
        <p>Content here</p>
        <span class='toggler'><button class="toggler" type="submit">Send Error Report</button></span>
    </div>
    <div class='toggled_content' style='display:none;'>
        <p>Hidden Content</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And then the jQuery is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.toggler').click(function() {
            $('.toggleHolder').slideUp().css('display', 'none')
            $('.toggled_conent').slideDown().css('display', '')
      });

    });​
```

I've tried so much that my brain doesn't function anymore and I know the answer will be "so easy I should have figured it out", but I'm stuck. I want the toggled content to appear and the toggleHolder to go away when you press the toggler.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide your hidden content via javascript instead of the `style`, and get rid of the `.css` calls:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.toggled_content').hide();

    $('.toggler').click(function() {
        $('.toggleHolder').slideUp();
        $('.toggled_content').slideDown();
    });

});​
```

Also you had a typo in your `.toggled_content` selector.

[Here's a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmLUd/).

Comment: tried your suggestion, that didn't work either. Here is the page for reference: http://conciergeoncampus.com/foobar

Comment: I've edited my post with a working example. Your site is generating an error somewhere, preventing the script from working.

Comment: I find this error using Chrome Web Developer tools: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL foobar:63" referring to the end of the .click(function(){ });

Comment: But I can see that the code works perfectly when I copy my source into jsfiddle. I'll investigate. Thanks josh.

Comment: just change toggled_content class name to something else but not named "toggled" in div and also in javascript and this will be working, you can check my answer...

Comment: Fixed the error by removing whitespace I didn't see before. Thanks again josh!

Comment: great! whitespace is always sneaky

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$('.toggler').click(function() {
        $('.toggleHolder').slideUp().hide();
        $('.toggled_conent').slideDown().show();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change class name = "toggled_content" to something else in div and jquery so this looks like

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.toggler').click(function() {
            $('.toggleHolder').slideUp().css('display', 'none');
            $('.haveOther').slideDown();
      });

    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='toggle_parent' style="background-color:#999;">
    <div class='toggleHolder'>
        <p>Content here</p>
        <span class='toggler'><button class="toggler" type="submit">Send Error Report</button></span>
    </div>
    <div class='haveOther' style='display:none;'>
        <p>Hidden Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will work for you.

Comment: you can remove inline style i have just used for getting view.